# secure PostgreSQL installation

Tags: security, postgresql

I want to install postgresql on my computer in such a way that no computer other than mine can see or access it.

I'm installing this on my work computer to store some GIS data, I don't want to worry about potential security issues if there are any that actually exist.

How do you suggest I install postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [this blogpost](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2007/08/18/securing-your-postgresql-database/).